# Relación muchos a muchos, Tabla intermedia tiene que recibir obligatoriamente todas las PK?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, base-de-datos

Tengo una duda con una relación muchos a muchos, según el siguiente diseño:

```
CREATE TABLE frutaDelAnio(
    frml_id                    NUMBER(6) NOT NULL, -- PK
    vfrm_codigo                NUMBER(6) NOT NULL);-- PK
```

`frml_id y vfrm_codigo son claves compuestas`.

```
CREATE TABLE tipoDeFruta(
    tip_id                    NUMBER(6) NOT NULL, --PK
    nombre                    VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE TablaIntermedia(
    frml_id                    NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
    vfrm_codigo                NUMBER(6) NOT NULL
    tip_id                     NUMBER(6) NOT NULL
);
```

La tabla `frutaDelAnio` Posee una clave compuesta `frml_id` y `vfrm_codigo`, mi pregunta es la siguiente es obligatorio que la tabla intermediaria tenga que utilizar  todas las PK que posee la tabla `frutaDelAnio`?, la duda nace por que datamodeler al hacer el modelado me hereda siempre las PK que tenga la tabla `frutaDelAnio`, pero solo necesito usar uno de esas PK en este caso el campo `frml_id`, existe un problema que eso sea así ?

Es decir necesito que mi tabla intermedia quede de la siguiente forma:

```
CREATE TABLE TablaIntermedia(
    frml_id                    NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
    tip_id                     NUMBER(6) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: No entiendo qué quieres decir con que *te hereda siempre las PK*  ¿? Lo correcto, según he entendido en el planteamiento, es que `TablaIntermedia` quede como  muestras al final. O sea, esa tabla debería tener una sola columna de la tabla `frutaDelAnio`, que sería su clave foránea en aquella tabla, todas las demás columnas, como `tip_id` serían ya columnas propias de `TablaIntermedia` o que expresen una relación con otra tabla.

Comment: La duda surgió debido a lo que esta haciendo datamodeler (herramienta de oracle), al realizar el modelo relacional me genera las ids de las tabla `frutaDelAnio` de manera automática para la tabla intermedia pasando a la tabla intermedia las dos claves compuestas que son PK de `frutaDelAnio`, entonces esto me da a pensar que debería ser obligatorio, mas allá de que mi tabla tenga estos campos quería que alguien me aclarase si es obligatorio según las reglas de bd que esto sea así?, si según esas dos PK solo quiero utilizar una esto es correcto?

Comment: Lo correcto es que tus tablas respondan a tu modelo de datos. El que una herramienta te haga algo por defecto no significa que haya que hacerlo así. Hay muchos otros factores que escapan de nuestro control (¿esa herramienta es configurable, está bien configurada, etc?). En el caso que planteas podrás saber si necesitas esas dos columnas respondiendo a la siguiente pregunta: ¿necesito esta referencia `vfrm_codigo` en `TablaIntermedia`? ¿por qué y para qué la necesito? Además hay más cosas a las que deberías responder: ¿por qué `frml_id` y `vfrm_codigo` son PK en `frutaDelAnio` ...?

Comment: ... ¿no debería ser una PK y otra tener una restricción `UNIQUE`? Como ya dije en mis primeros comentarios, creo que en `TablaIntermedia` sólo necesitarías el identificador `frml_id`, asumiendo que esa columna identificaría a cada registro por separado en `frutaDelAnio` (es una columna auto_incremental).  Si no fuera el caso, lo más correcto (creo yo) sería dotar a esa tabla de una columna auto_incremental que sería PK, y luego combinar las columnas que necesites bajo una restricción `UNIQUE`...

Comment: ... o sea, abordamos dos cosas muy distintas: la columna que es PK (auto-incremental) serviría para ser usada como llave foránea en otras tablas y las columnas que son `UNIQUE` (que pueden ser dos, tres, cuatro...) servirían para indicar en la tabla local qué registros no deberían repetirse. No sé si me explico.

Comment: si `frutaDelAnio` utiliza una llave compuesta entonces tendrias que pasar la llave compuesta (los dos PK) a la tabla intermedia, ya que con una PK sola no tendrias una referencia univoca.

Comment: pero como dice el colega @A.Cedano, tenes que fijarte si es verdaderamente necesario tener una PK compuesta para `frutaDelAnio`, en caso contrario es aconsejable usar una PK auto-incremental  para aumentar la prestaciones de la base de datos

Comment: @A.Cedano, según mi modelo no necesito usar la clave compuesta solo necesito usar una pk de la tabla `frutaDelAnio`, el problema como te comentaba es que la herramienta me esta obligando a utilizar las dos PK y por eso me surgió la duda de que si tiene que ser obligatorio, al final y al cabo cuando esta me entrega el script DML/DDL puedo cambiar esa asociación que me crea la herramienta, lo que necesito en la tabla intermedia lo tengo más que claro, mi duda principal como te decía era lo que me generaba la herramienta de manera obligatoria y quedo con esa duda con las PK de `frutaDelAnio`.

Comment: @A.Cedano, según lo que me dices `Lo correcto es que tus tablas respondan a tu modelo de datos. El que una herramienta te haga algo por defecto no significa que haya que hacerlo así. ` , con este comentario me dejas mas claro, tenia una duda existencial con lo que hacia la herramienta, gracias por la paciencia.

Comment: Entiendo. Quizá la herramienta hacía eso porque ambas columnas estaban declaradas como PK y (creo yo) la herramienta asume en ese caso que para obtener una referencia válida y segura hay que incluir ambas columnas en la otra tabla. Ahora bien, conviene que reflexiones sobre si realmente las dos columnas deben seguir siendo PK en la tabla `frutaDelAnio`, lo más común es tener una sola columna como PK y, en caso de necesitar **otro criterio de unicidad adicional** (no siempre es necesario), crear una restricción `UNIQUE` con la(s) columna(s) que no deberían repetirse.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que hace tu programa de modelado es darle consistencia a las relaciones, si tienes una tabla que su clave única se compone de dos o más campos, entonces el programa tomará todos los campos que conformen esta clave.

Así que tienes dos opciones:

1. Tabla con los 3 campos y relacionada (mantendrá la consistencia del modelo).
2. Tabla con dos campos no relacionada (manipulada por código).

¿Te molesta un campo de más? ¿Colapsara la memoria del sistema por este campo? si no es así creo que mejor mantienes la consistencia, ya que no te afectará mayormente y no tendrás que preocuparte de errores a futuro.

De lo contrario crea la tabla suelta en el modelo, sin relacionarla y mantén tu consistencia en el código de tu aplicativo con cuidado.

Comment: Así es el programa me estaba creando las relaciones por consistencia, pero no es lo que necesitaba en ese momento, me surgió la duda existencial debido a lo que estaba haciendo datamodeler al obligarme a realizar esto, pero según lo que me dijo @A.Cedano en los comentarios me quedo claro que lo que la herramienta hace no tiene que ser lo que responde a mi modelo de datos por defecto, ahora mismo solo utilizo las relaciones que si responden a mi modelo de datos. pero eso era la duda con la herramienta y lo que hacia con el modelo.